# Axis on Excel Chart has too many entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I think pictures say more than words:

[image: My chart]

I want to cut this off. The entire lower section is not needed, I only want 12000 to 18000. How do I manage this?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-scale-of-the-vertical-value-axis-in-a-chart-05973661-e56a-4486-a9f3-f9ce41df0021#ID0EAACAAA=2010,2007

Comment: @Máté Juhász Thanks for your answer, I solved it with the link you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by right clicking the axis, click on format axis and under axis options I clicked on fixed besides minimum and maximum. I then entered the values I needed.

Comment: After Máté gave you the answer, you posted the solution and then voted yourself 10 points?

Comment: To be fair, Mate gave him a comment and did not answer the question.  Once M had the answer, it was documented just like any other answer.  And Stack has always [encouraged answering your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: It never hurts to cite the source of your answer.